# How to set JavaFX TextField to wrap text inside field

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, word-wrap

I need hlep with figuring out how to wrap the text in the JavaFX TextField object.

So my code gets a file name from the user, opens the file by pasting the contents of the text file into the text field. Then the user can edit the text and save it into the same file.

My code does all of the above so that's not what I need help with. The JavaFX TextField object does not seem to have a way to wrap the text in the text box. It ends up looking like this:
[image: current textfield layout]

Alt Image Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q2yU5ox6WA5EwS3YSxaKoqUDpCxpbPmu

I want to wrap the text for obvious reasons. Below is my code (minus the import statements)

```java
public class TextEditor extends Application
{
    private Button button = new Button();
    private TextField text = new TextField();
    private Label label = new Label("Enter filename:");
    private String filename = "";
    String filetext = "";
    Scanner file = new Scanner("");
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        GridPane myPane = new GridPane();
        myPane.setHgap(10);
        myPane.setVgap(10);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
        primaryStage.show();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Find File");

        myPane.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

        label.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        myPane.add(label, 0, 0, 3, 1);

        text.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        text.setPrefWidth(480);
        text.setPrefHeight(400);

        myPane.add(text, 0, 1);

        button = new Button("Submit Filename");
        button.setPrefSize(180, 50);
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                if(button.getText().equals("Save Changes"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                        pw = new PrintWriter(fos);

                        System.out.println("Saving changes in " + filename);
                        pw.println(text.getText());
                        pw.close();
                        primaryStage.close();
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(button.getText().equals("Submit Filename"))
                {
                    filename = text.getText();  
                    try
                    {
                        file = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File(filename)));


                        while(file.hasNextLine())
                        {
                            String line = file.nextLine();
                            System.out.println(line);
                            filetext += line + "\n";
                        }

                        System.out.println("File text: " + filetext);
                        text.setText(filetext);
                        button.setText("Save Changes");
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException exc)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Cannot find file. Program aborted.");
                        primaryStage.close();
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        myPane.add(button, 0, 2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Would love some assistance getting the text to wrap. Do I need to not use a JavaFX TextField? Should I use something else?

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT*

**SOLUTION FOUND**

I changed the TextField text to a TextArea, removed the text.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT) line and added a text.setWrapText(true) (as suggested below) and now the program works great. Thanks Fabian and Zephyr!

Comment: The only control from the standard API that does this seems to be `TextArea`. You'd of course need to prevent a line break from being added. BTW: not sure how you to handle an amount of text not fitting the control. Grow the control? Scrollbars? (`TextArea does this`) Something else?

Comment: As fabian said, a simple `TextArea` is what you need here. Simply set the `textArea.setWrapText(true)` property and you're good to go.

Comment: Changing from a TextField to a TextArea worked! Thanks so much!